# Create RAID array of image files

Tags: mount, raid, disk-image

OK, so I've got three image files in `/home/`, and they each reside on different physical drives:

```
image1.img

image2.img

image3.img
```

Each image is the same size, and I want to put the images themselves into RAID0.

How should I go about RAIDing them?

EDIT:  Using mdadm I get this error:

[image]

EDIT: Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

[image]

EDIT:  Output of `sudo gparted /dev/md0`

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a RAID-0 drive which has thrice the size of the image files and is stripped between the three image files?

Comment: Yes.  The idea is to be able to create a RAID unit that can span multiple drives without actually placing the drives in RAID.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/mdstat` say about this error?

Comment: See edit to question

Comment: What are the media below the image files? Based on the error message they do not support seek...

Comment: They are blank.  I'm trying to create a completely new and blank RAID disk

Comment: I literally just did `touch image#.img`  for each one.  Is there something else I should do?

Comment: If you want a RAID unit you need to allocate some space as well…

Comment: And how should I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27541/discussion-between-lemonslice-and-daniel).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install the Linux software RAID you need to install the `mdadm` package.

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm
```

If you want to make a software RAID-0 from the three image files, you need to create loop devices for each image files:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop1 image1.img
sudo losetup /dev/loop2 image2.img
sudo losetup /dev/loop3 image3.img
```

After you can create a RAID-0 array from them:

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=3 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3
```

Comment: command mdadm not found

Comment: You have to install the package `mdadm`.

Comment: See edit to question

Comment: That's with a fresh install of mdadm.

Answer (score 1):

If your system matches the basic requirements you could use `zfs` ([8 GB RAM, 64-bit system](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html)):

Add repo and update package list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Install package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs
```

[Create a striped vdev](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS/ZPool) (with no redundancy, but you asked for RAID0):

```
sudo zpool create vol0 ~/image[1-3].img
```

This creates the stripe and mounts it at /vol0.

```
sudo zfs create vol0/filesystem
```

This [creates a zfs file system on the stripe](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gaztn/index.html) and mounts it at /vol0/filesystem. Use

```
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/filesystem vol0/filesystem
```

if you want to change the mount point.

You can also add automatic compression:

```
sudo zfs create vol0/filesystem/compressed
sudo zfs set compression=on vol0/filesystem/compressed
```

Now everything you put into /mnt/filesystem/compressed will automatically be compressed.

Comment: "E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-zfs"

Comment: And this should also work with iso files, right?

Comment: Forgot to add instructions on how to add the repo. Have edited now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with iso files... The instructions will create a blank file system striped over the 3 files in question. Do you have data in your iso files that you somehow wish to access on a striped partition?

Comment: No, I was just curious as to whether or not it could be done with, say a DVD-RW for instance, or something like that.

Comment: Still the same unable to find the package.

Comment: I guess it could be done with a DVD-RW, but I fail to see the point.

Comment: I forgot to add an update step. Have done so now.

Comment: Aha!  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

> I literally just did touch image#.img for each one. Is there something else I should do?

This is indeed the problem. The files are 0 bytes, and you cannot seek inside them. You have to make files that actually have a size. It can be a [a sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) if you want:

```
[/tmp]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=1.img bs=1M count=25 conv=sparse
25+0 records in
25+0 records out
26214400 bytes (26 MB, 25 MiB) copied, 0.00334608 s, 7.8 GB/s
[/tmp]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=2.img bs=1M count=25 conv=sparse
25+0 records in
25+0 records out
26214400 bytes (26 MB, 25 MiB) copied, 0.00347987 s, 7.5 GB/s
[/tmp]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=3.img bs=1M count=25 conv=sparse
25+0 records in
25+0 records out
26214400 bytes (26 MB, 25 MiB) copied, 0.00330069 s, 7.9 GB/s
[/tmp]$ du  1.img 
0       1.img
```

Now I can make loopdevices and assemble array:

```
[/tmp]$ sudo losetup loop0 1.img 
[/tmp]$ sudo losetup loop1 2.img 
[/tmp]$ sudo losetup loop2 3.img 
[/tmp]$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=3 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
[/tmp]$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0 
mke2fs 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 73728 1k blocks and 18432 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 8123197c-a9aa-434d-9233-103fe20727ed
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        8193, 24577, 40961, 57345

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
[/tmp]$ mkdir mnt/
[/tmp]$ sudo mount /dev/md0 mnt/
[/tmp]$ df -h mnt/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0         66M  1.3M   60M   3% /tmp/mnt
[/tmp]$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] 
md0 : active raid0 loop2[2] loop1[1] loop0[0]
      73728 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
[/tmp]$ du -h 1.img 2.img 3.img 
1.3M    1.img
1.6M    2.img
1.6M    3.img
```

Sparse files will grow up to the maximum size, as data is written to them. They will *not* shrink if files inside the filesystem is deleted.